# Is the decay of a neutral rho meson into a neutral pi meson and a photon forbidden?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, mesons, pions

Is the decay of a neutral rho meson into a neutral pi meson and a photon forbidden? It doesn´t look like parity conservation or charge conservation is violated but I haven´t found this decay is possible on the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the decay is not forbidden, even though it is a rare decay as you could check on [PDG](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/listings/rpp2020-list-rho-770.pdf). If you're interested you can check this (and many others) article:

- A. V. Anisovich *et al.*, "The $ρ → γπ$ and $ω → γπ$ decays in quark-model approach and estimation of coupling for pion emission by quark", [*Phys. Atom. Nuclei* **73**, 462–477 (2010)](https://doi.org/10.1134/S1063778810030087), [arXiv:0901.4854](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.4854).

Comment: Right. Being electromagnetic, it is suppressed wrt to the strong one by four orders of magnitude. Spot on.